# Javadoc shows Error "reference not found" although reference cleary exists

Tags: java-8, javadoc

With Java8 the javadoc checks became stricter. The common solution is to disable the strict javadoc checking. Nevertheless, I started trying to fix the errors in some projects.
But there is one error I don't get fixed.

The corresponding class:

```
package foo;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
[...]

public class MyClass {

  [...]

  /**
   * @see TextArea#getValue()
   */
  public String getValue() {
      [...]
  }

  /**
   * @see TextArea#setValue(String value)
   */
  public void setValue(String value) {
      [...]
  }

  /**
   * @see TextArea#setValue(String, boolean)
   */
  public void setValue(String value, boolean fireEvents) {
      [...]
  }
}
```

And the error message:

```
[ERROR] ...\MyClass.java:44: error: reference not found
[ERROR] * @see TextArea#setValue(String value)  
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] ...\MyClass.java:51: error: reference not found
[ERROR] * @see TextArea#setValue(String, boolean)
```

The error message states that it cannot find `TextArea` in the Javadoc of the `setValue`-Methods - but on the other hand has no problems to find `TextArea` on the `getValue`-Method.

As far as I can say, I followed [How to specify a name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#JSWOR654) as well as [@see reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDDIEDI).

Any clues? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer now, it's a bit tricky!

- `TextArea` extends `ValueBoxBase<String>`
- `TextArea#getValue()` has no Parameters, so everything is fine
- The Method `TextArea#setValue(String value)` does not exist in `TextArea`, it is rather defined in the superclass: `ValueBoxBase#setValue(Object, boolean)`.

But there it is! There is "technically" no method `setValue(String)`. It's rather `setValue(Object)`. There is either no way for javadoc to resolve this on its own or it's just a bug.

Thus, the only was I found to solve this is using the reference to the superclass.

```
/**
 * @see com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ValueBoxBase#setValue(Object, boolean)
 */
```

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905127/overridden-methods-in-javadoc)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
/**
 * @see TextArea#getValue()
 */
```

Try:

```
/**
 * @see com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea#getValue()
 */
```

Comment: I already tried with no success  `[ERROR] ..\MyClass.java:51: error: reference not found
[ERROR] * @see com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea#setValue(String, boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the sameproblem.
But I solved without () of method.

```
@see ClassTest.method
```